# Why I'm getting CS1012: "Too many characters in character literal" and CS0019?

Tags: c#

When trying to upload something to Imgur, I have to put an Authorization in. I do it with `WebRequest.Headers` but it gives me three errors.

2 times CS1012 error

> Too many characters in character literal

and 1 time CS0019 error:

> Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'method group'

This is the code:

```
webRequest.Headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + GetToken;
```

What have I done wrong, how can I fix it, and how does it work?
This is uploading with Imgur, I don't know if the 'GetToken' thing is right but it's to get the AccessToken, which should work correctly if I'm right.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You're trying to use single quotes for string literals - that's invalid in C#. Single quotes are for *character* literals (`char`). You need double quotes for string literals. You also need parentheses for a method call:

```
webRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + GetToken();
```

(Note that this has nothing to do with imgur or `WebRequest` - it's just normal C#.)

Links to MSDN explanations with samples:

- [CS1012 - "Too many characters in character literal"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/185szk2f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [CS0019 - "Operator 'operator' cannot be applied to operands of type 'type' and 'type'"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63h61ky.aspx)

Comment: Oh! HEHE, I see. Damnit I just saw this in another thread and forgot I had single quotes. Thank you, it works now. Now see if I can upload it.

Comment: @Stepepper: It's worth noting that the compiler gave you two hints about this... always read the error messages carefully :)

Comment: @Stepepper - one other hint - go to error window and click F1 - it will open MSDN topic for given error. Theses articles often have samples that show most typical cases of the error.

Comment: WOW! dumb mistake (@ me). Too many languages at the same time here.