# CS1012´´Too many characters in character literal´´

Tags: c#

I' beginner with C#. I was coding my first game and got error:Too many characters in character literal. How to fix it?

```
if (Input.GetAxisRaw('Horizontal') < 0.5f)                
{         
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw('Horizontal' * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)));
}
```

Comment: Use a double quotes " instead of '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting CS1012: "Too many characters in character literal" and CS0019?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600191/why-im-getting-cs1012-too-many-characters-in-character-literal-and-cs0019)

Comment: Can someone explain to me what does this code: _'Horizontal' * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime_?

Comment: @Steve, don't working, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You should use double quotes instead:

```
if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < 0.5f);
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 things wrong.

First, `Input.GetAxisRaw` takes `string` as a parameter and string literals with used double quotes `""` not single quotes `''`. Single quotes are used for `char` type. That's why you should it as;

```
Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")
```

Second, that method returns `float` and if you do some calculations about that, the right syntax should be

```
Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime
```

not

```
Input.GetAxisRaw('Horizontal' * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime))
```

Comment: Well, at least this is a plausible explanation of that _string mutiplication operator_

Comment: @Steve _string mutiplication operator_ Nice one :)

Comment: Oh, well I thought I was being original, but there is also a question about that: [Can I “multiply” a string (in C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532892/can-i-multiply-a-string-in-c)