# Combining JavaScript and ASP.NET MVC HTML code issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I plan to use some `Model` properties to manage **JavaScript** code in **HTML/Razor**.

```
   "columnDefs": [
               {

                   "render": function (data, type, row) {                        

                       @if (Model.ConfigViewModel.AllowDeleteAnyUsers)
                       {
                           return '<center><img class="cursor-hand" onclick="javascript:ConfirmRemoveUser(this)"  data-userId="' + row.Id + '"  data-userName="' + row.UserName + '"   src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></center>'
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           return '<center><img class="cursor-hand" onclick="javascript:ConfirmRemoveUser(this)"  data-userId="' + row.Id + '"  data-userName="' + row.UserName + '"   src="images/delete-disabled.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></center>'
                       } 
                   },
                   "targets": 3
               }
```

But elements of JS code like `row.Id` are giving errors like.

> Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character
>   literal

Any clue how to combine **Razor** and **JS**?

Comment: "You're trying to use single quotes for string literals, ..."
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600191/why-im-getting-cs1012-too-many-characters-in-character-literal-and-cs0019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write it like this:

```
 @if (Model.ConfigViewModel.AllowDeleteAnyUsers)
 {
     <text>
     return '<center><img class="cursor-hand" onclick="javascript:ConfirmRemoveUser(this)"  data-userId="' + row.Id + '"  data-userName="' + row.UserName + '"   src="images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" border="0"></center>';
     </text>
  }
```