# if statement in a foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach

I want to add an if statement in this foreach loop but it obviously throws up errors.

> Too many characters in character literal

This is what I did and what i want to achieve with this. is there a way i can do this?

```
foreach (User user in this.oSkype.Friends)
        {
            if (user.OnlineStatus == 'olsOffline') {
                this.listBoxControl1.Items.Add(user.Handle + ' Offline');
            } else {
                this.listBoxControl1.Items.Add(user.Handle + ' Online');
            }
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it obviously throws up errors"? Without getting into detail of the Skype API you are using.. the code looks like it should work without any errors.

Comment: change ' to " .. a bit more effort shouldve went into this code

Comment: What is the error and can you separate what you have done and what you want to achieve into different sections.

Comment: The problem is the use of single quotes instead of double quotes for string literals. Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600191/why-im-getting-cs1012-too-many-characters-in-character-literal-and-cs0019. First hit in Google by searching for your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dealing with type `string` not `char`. So update single quotes to double quotes:

```
foreach (User user in this.oSkype.Friends)
        {
            if (user.OnlineStatus == "olsOffline") {
                this.listBoxControl1.Items.Add(user.Handle + " Offline");
            } else {
                this.listBoxControl1.Items.Add(user.Handle + " Online");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah .... woops, thanks