# Trying to get session value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascipt script in my .aspx file . I'm using Session facade, but I don't it is  important. I can not get value from Session value. Why ??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function navHyperlink() {
        var group = '<%= (Session["GroupId"]!=null ? Session["GroupId"].ToString(): "-1") %>';
        switch (group) {
            case '2':
                navigateURL = '/TelefonListe.aspx';
                break;

            case '1':
                navigateURL = '/TelefonListe.aspx';
                break;

            case '0':
                navigateURL = '/MeineTelefonListe.aspx';
                break;

            default:
                return navigateURL = '/Account/Login.aspx';
                break;

        }
        var a = document.getElementById('TelefonListeLink'); //or grab it by tagname etc
        a.href = navigateURL;
        return true;
    }

 </script>                   
 <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" id ="TelefonListeLink" onclick="navHyperlink();">Telefonliste</a>
```

I tried with only `var group = '<%= Session["GroupId"].Tostring() %>';` but sometimes `Session["GroupId"]` can be null and I have *error CS1073*. but in this way I have *CS1012*. Big Thx for help. `GroupId` is `int nullable`.

Comment: CS1012 has answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20600191/215552. Why not just do `var group = '<%= Session["GroupId"] %>';`? Your `switch` would handle if `group` is `'null'`...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var group = '<%= Session["GroupId"].Tostring() %>';`you can use hidden field and assign value to it from  backend after proper handling, and then find the value of hidden field from front end using jquery or js.