# MSSQL asp.net insert to table doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, insert

Let me refraise the question

I have an ASP.Net page with data fields and 2 buttons one to check if a company exsists (this one works).

Button 2 needs to insert the values

```
 [ID]
      ,[BEDRIJF]
      ,[FUNCTIE]
      ,[TITEL]
      ,[VOORNAAM]
      ,[VOORLETTERS]
      ,[TUSSENVOEGSEL]
      ,[ACHTERNAAM]
      ,[SEXE]
      ,[ADRES]
      ,[PCPLAATS]
      ,[LAND]
      ,[EMAIL]
      ,[BRANCHE]
      ,[TELEFOON]
      ,[MOBIEL]
      ,[DATUM_BRIEF]
      ,[VEBAN]
      ,[PAYOFF]
```

From the textboxes radio buttons and dropdown list on the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/jubels_logo_vlakje_magenta.png" style="margin-left: 0px" />
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 80px">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Ingevoerd Door :"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Bedrijfsnaam :"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Branche"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="BRANCHE" DataValueField="BRANCHE">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FUP-DataConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [BRANCHE] FROM [Branches]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Geslacht"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <asp:ListItem Value="M">Man</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="V">Vrouw</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Voorletters "></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Voornaam "></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Tussenvoegsel"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Achternaam "></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text="Functie"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text="Straat - huisnummer"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Width="16px"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Postcode - plaats"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Width="41px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Telefoon"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Mobiel"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server">06</asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text="Brieftext"></asp:Label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList3" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
            <asp:ListItem>Normaal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>EX-Klanten/Propects</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Vormgever</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Fotograaf</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>

       <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Ondertekening"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
            <asp:ListItem>Fred</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Jeroen</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Fons</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>


        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Check Database op bestaand record" OnClick="Button1_Click" /><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Voeg toe aan Database" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But this dosnt work, it doenst insert nor does it change the label 16 text to Data Saved or Data not saved.

Can some one point out why the button is not working.

Some insight SQL and SQL connections arent my normal programming area, in normaly build basic windows app with simple layouts and simpel functionality as requested by coworkers.

the button click funtion in aspx.cs file

```
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FUP-DataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_insert", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEDRIJF", TextBox17.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VOORNAAM", TextBox6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACHTERNAAM", TextBox8.Text);

                con.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (i != 1)
                {
                    Label16.Text = ("Data Saved");

                    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "5;url=Default2.aspx");
                }

                else 

                {
                    Label16.Text = ("Data Not Saved");

                    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "5;url=Default2.aspx");
                }
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //log error 
                   //display friendly error to user
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (conn != null)
                    {
                        //cleanup connection i.e close 
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: It did not gave an error it is simply not inserting the values in to the table Data

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data Values (@BEDRIJF,@VOORNAAM)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEDRIJF", BEDRIJF);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VOORNAAM", VOORNAAM);
```

Do not contain your parameters in inverted commas.

[Why I'm getting CS1012: "Too many characters in character literal" and CS0019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20600191/why-im-getting-cs1012-too-many-characters-in-character-literal-and-cs0019)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks for the edit, but still the values are not insterted to the DB

Comment: Anything with single quotes in C# is treated as a character (char type) . since the parameters have more than one character i.e they are a string of characters , use double quotes to contain them.

Comment: @Sojab0on what happens when you debug? Have you run a trace on the SQL side to see what is happening there?

Comment: Be careful using AddWithValue for ad hoc queries. It does not always get the correct datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are using Parameter wise Insert so

```
string BEDRIJF = TextBox17.Text;
            string VOORNAAM = TextBox6.Text; // Scrub user data
            string VOORLETTERS = TextBox5.Text;
            string Tussenvoegsel = TextBox7.Text;
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FUP-DataConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data Values ('@BEDRIJF','@VOORNAAM')";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEDRIJF", BEDRIJF);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VOORNAAM", VOORNAAM);
                    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (rowsAffected == 1)
                    {
                        //Success notification
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Error notification
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log error 
                //display friendly error to user
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    //cleanup connection i.e close 
                }
```

See this part where you are wrong

```
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Data Values ('@BEDRIJF','@VOORNAAM')";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEDRIJF", BEDRIJF);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VOORNAAM", VOORNAAM);
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at the code, but when i try your changes it gives back to many character in character literal on the cmd.Paramerter lines

Comment: it gives back to many character in character literal on the cmd.Paramerter lines, can you post As Image here

Comment: its added to the original post.

Comment: Be careful using AddWithValue for ad hoc queries. It does not always get the correct datatype. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: big tanks for the help but still when i use the button to add the given values it does not add them in de DB, i added a message at the point //display friendly error to user so it changes a label at the bottom to Gegevens niet toegevoegd aan de database if its not adding them.

And if it does at the point  //Success notification it changes the same label to De Ingevoerde gegeevns zijn aan database toegevoegd.

Have added my login page button code that validates user for the Users table in the same database, cant that code be alterd to insert the string values

Comment: letting it rest have tried the changes sugested but still it wont add to the database.

Comment: haveng it let rest for a while and triedit again with the updated codes you gave @Imran but still no luck in inserting the values in to the table.